# Cannot login as admin in production

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am having trouble logging in as admin when I switch to production. I get the following error:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder - Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

I am guessing I would have to change the admin password directly in the database (table blc_admin_user), to an encrypted one? If so, what would it be?
Also I am hoping to use the same database created in development for production, I hope that is not an issue.

Note that I am using the default admin login (password: admin). 
version 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to encrypt the `admin` password with BCrypt and put that in the `BLC_ADMIN_USER` table. Here is the update script to do that:

```
UPDATE BLC_ADMIN_USER SET PASSWORD = '$2a$06$NtRCQoGXWEgBClwBO8b1AeBqIP1elvZNuZqR/57Yjfw4kV/M0vljG' WHERE LOGIN = 'admin';
```